# How Kotlin objects & companion objects & lazy works with memory

Tags: java, memory, scope, kotlin

I couldn't find anywhere about how objects, companion objects and lazy works with memory.
Can anyone here explain me how they work with memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a quite vague question and can be answered by looking into bytecode.

## [Object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations)

Object declaration is a singleton. It has a static field called `INSTANCE` which gets initialized in static block (`<clinit>`).

## [Companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)

Companion is a kind of inner class, but is a singleton and behaves like object declaration.

## [Lazy delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)

Lazy delegate (every delegate) is a separate object. Each time you create a lazy field, a delegate object gets instantiated.